# Change webpage logo for every user in django

Tags: python, html, django, django-views

How can I change website logo in **base.html** for every other user login into Django platform? For example: User-A (request.user.customer.public_id) when login, will see different logo on website after uploading his logo in folder, while User-B will see different and so on.
By default, if no user upload logo, then they will see default logo on the website.

```
<div class="container-fluid" title="Website">
      <a data-testid="linkElement"
  href="https://www.google.com" target="_self" class="xQ_iF"><img src="{% static 'logo.png' %}" alt="google"
  style="width:90px;height:60px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; padding-left: 32px;  position: absolute;">
       <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup"
    aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="true" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    </button>

      </a>

 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">

        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto" style = "margin-left: auto;">
        <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'home' %}"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>&nbsp; Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
    
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="https://www.google.com/support-page"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>&nbsp; Support<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
    
    
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a  class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink-4" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">
        <i class="fa fa-user-circle-o"></i>&nbsp; {{request.user}}</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" style="background-color: #
        </div>
        </li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    
          </div>
      </div>
      </nav>
      </div>
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You should share your code like: The **views**, **models** and **template**

Comment: @DeeAdamu is right here, you should share all relevant files and which kind of logo are you talking about please tell, otherwise you'll get opinion based answer as your question also, see how do I ask a good question [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You could tie this into your database structure for the users themselves. In this case, I would recommend adding a picture field to a new model associated to the user (or better a group that the user is associated with):

```
class UserLogos(models.Model):
    """
    Model for storing User Logos
    """
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        verbose_name=_("user"),
        help_text=_("The associated user"),
    )
    photo = models.ImageField(
        _("photo"),
        upload_to="logo_photos",
        help_text=_("Your logo photo"),
        default="logo_photos/default.png",
    )
```

Then in your views, simply call this item up:

```
def index(request):
    """
    Index View

    Render the server configured index page
    """
    return render(
        request,
        "index.html",
        {
            "userLogo": models.UserLogos.filter(user=request.user).first()
        },
    )
```

And finally in your html template:

```
<img src="{{ userLogo.photo.url }}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume we have a route `dynamic_logo_page/` which uses  `dynamic_logo_page.html` template and the corresponding view name is `dynamic_logo_view`.

```py
# Inside views.py

def get_logo_url(user_id):
    # TODO: implement logic to get the logo_url based on user_id
    return some_logo_url

def dynamic_logo_view(request):
  if request.user.is_authenticated:
      logo_url = get_logo_url(request.user.id)
      content = {
        "user_id": request.user.id,
        "logo_url": logo_url
      }
        
  return render(request, 'dynamic_logo_page.html', content)
```

```html
<!-- Inside dynamic_logo_page.html -->
...
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
  <div>Hi {{ user_id }}, here is your personalized logo below:</div>
  <img src="{{ logo_url }}" alt='logo'/>
{% endif %}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution depends if you want a random logo shown to each user on every request, or if each user has their own specific logo.

#### Random logo for each user, different for each request

If you want the logo to be random for every request, you could provide a list of logos in the template context, and then use a [random filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#random) to pick a logo from the list at random.

```html
<img id="logo" src="{% static logo_options|random %}">
```

This would result in a logo that statistically could be the same for two users at the same time, but that depends on how many logo variants are available.

#### Specific logo for each user, same for each request

To have the same logo for a user, then a logo must be specified and stored somehow. This could be achieved by adding a `ImageField` to the `User` model, and then retrieving this field in the template.

There are multiple ways to extend the `User` model built into Django, see here for a tutorial on this: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html

Depending on your solution, the template may end up looking something like this:

```html
<img id="logo" src="{% static user.logo.url %}">
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved this issue.
Here is my models.py

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank =True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    platformLogo= models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_path, default='logo.png', null=True, blank=False)
```

Here is the function where logos will be saved.

```
def upload_path(instance, filename):
    filename = str(date.today())
    name = instance.user.customer
    name1 = str(name)
    name = name1.replace('@','_')
    return f'{name}/{filename}.jpg'
```

My settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")]


MEDIA_URL = '/platformLogo/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/platformLogo')
```

Here is HTML template

```
<div class="container-fluid" title="Website">

{% if request.user.is_staff %} 

  <a data-testid="linkElement"
href="https://www.google.com" target="_self" class="xQ_iF"><img src="{% static 'logo.png' %}" alt="google"
style="width:90px;height:60px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; padding-left: 32px;  position: absolute;">

{% else %}

 <a data-testid="linkElement"
 href="https://www.google.com" target="_self" class="xQ_iF"><img src="{% static user.customer.platformLogo.url %}" alt="google"
 style="width:90px;height:60px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; padding-left: 32px;  position: absolute;">
   
{% endif %}

   <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup"
aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="true" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
  </button>
  </a>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">

    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto" style = "margin-left: auto;">
    <li class="nav-item active">
    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'home' %}"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>&nbsp; Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    </li>

    <li class="nav-item active">
      <a class="nav-link" href="https://www.google.com/support-page"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>&nbsp; Support<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>


    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a  class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink-4" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">
    <i class="fa fa-user-circle-o"></i>&nbsp; {{request.user}}</a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" style="background-color: #
    </div>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </div>

      </div>
  </div>
  </nav>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found one more alternative way to solve this problem. Below is my models.py file.

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank =True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    platformLogoUrl = models.CharField(max_length=500, default='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3e/Google_2011_logo.png/640px-Google_2011_logo.png', null=True)
```

HTML Template

```
    <div class="container-fluid" title="Website">

    {% if request.user.is_staff %} 

    <a href="https://www.google.com" <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3e/Google_2011_logo.png/640px-Google_2011_logo.png" alt="google"
    style="width:90px;height:60px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; padding-left: 32px;  position: absolute;">

    {% else %}

    <a data-testid="linkElement"
    href="https://www.google.com"><img src="{{request.user.customer.platformLogoUrl}}" alt="google"
    style="width:90px;height:60px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; padding-left: 32px;  position: absolute;">
   
    {% endif %}

    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup"
    aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="true" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    </button>
    </a>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">

    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto" style = "margin-left: auto;">
    <li class="nav-item active">
    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'home' %}"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>&nbsp; Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    </li>

    <li class="nav-item active">
      <a class="nav-link" href="https://www.google.com/support-page"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>&nbsp; Support<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>


    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a  class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink-4" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">
    <i class="fa fa-user-circle-o"></i>&nbsp; {{request.user}}</a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" style="background-color: #
    </div>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </div>

      </div>
  </div>
  </nav>
  </div>
```