# How can I hide current uploaded image location path in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I have made a feature in Django where every user can change his platform's logo. The image selected by the user will be saved in static/{user.customer.public_id}/platformLogo/image.jpg. When i save the changes, i can see the uploaded image's path which also contain unique public ID which i don't want user to see for security purpose. Can anyone help me to hide this image path in Django for user? Attaching my code part here below.

[Here we can see the image path which has unique ID in path, which we need to hide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NbJD.png)

[Here is the uploaded image path directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaJHZ.png)

Here is my models.py

```
from sre_constants import CATEGORY
from unicodedata import category
from attr import fields
from django.db import models
from datetime import date
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
import uuid

def upload_path(instance, filename):
    filename = str(date.today())
    name = instance.user.customer.public_id.hex
    return f'{name}/platformLogo/{filename}.jpg'


class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank =True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    public_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default = uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    otp_code = models.CharField(max_length=6, null=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    profile_pic= models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_path, default='logo.png', null=True, blank=False,)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

Here is my views.py

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def accountSetting(request):
    customer = request.user.customer
    form = CustomerForm(instance= customer)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CustomerForm(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES, instance=customer)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

    context = {'form': form}
    if request.user.is_anonymous:
        return redirect("/") 
    return render(request, 'account-settings.html', context)
```

Here is my forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Customer
from django import forms


class CustomerForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields  = '__all__'
        exclude = ['user', 'email','name','otp_code']


class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields  = ['username','first_name','last_name', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']
```

Here is settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]

MEDIA_URL = '/platformLogo/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/platformLogo')
```

Comment: I found an alternative way to solve this. In this way, i am able to keep UUID away from public's eye and make the job done.
[Alternative method to solve this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72471628/13543088)

Answer (score 0):

Since you already made public_id UUID, why not hash the logo and image name?

Answer (score 0):

In Django environments I’ve used xsendfile with Apache or nginx. You end up placing the images in a folder that is accessible by Apache and served by apache, but can only be served after a request to the Django backend. It prevents all of the logos being visible to prying eyes.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? If you have some relevant resource for this, please do share! Thanks.

Comment: I used this to get started https://pythonhosted.org/xsendfile/howto.html